# PayPal Smart Buttons used in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, integration, paypal

I am looking to implement PayPal Smart Buttons to a LWC.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

In short, this feature requires two HTML lines in the template:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test"></script>
<script>paypal.Buttons().render('body');</script>
```

Since we are unable to load that in the HTML file, I was able to add them to the HTML file using javascript and manipulating the DOM:

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test";
document.body.appendChild(script);
const buttonscript = document.createElement("script");
console.log('Button Script Start'+buttonscript);
buttonscript.innerHTML = 'paypal.Buttons().render(#paypal-button-container-39);';
console.log('Button Script innerhtml'+buttonscript.innerHTML);
document.body.appendChild(buttonscript);
console.log('All Loaded');
```

When these tags are added to the HMTL, no button displays. Any thoughts?

What are the best practice/how do we implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Scripts cannot be loaded this way. Currently, the only way to load such a contraption is in Visualforce. You can create a VF page that can include whatever HTML it likes, and then you put that Visualforce page into an iframe in a component of your choice.

Comment: Ah! Is there any workaround to make that ifame not look/function as an iframe?

Comment: @RobFoster You can remove the border with styles, but it'll still function as an iframe. However, this will probably be acceptable for most use cases.

Comment: Going to give that a try. Is there any other ways to make this a streamlined. For example, not use smartbuttons.